# PostgreSQL - export one row with the maximum count?

Tags: postgresql

So i have the following relevant tables:

Character (characterid, firstname, lastname, kindid,genderid, ismagic)

and

killedby (characterid, killerid, bookid, year)

(its a database with harry potter theme for university training puroses)

the question is: export the character with the highest killcount (characterid, firstname, lastname, killcount)

my approach is:

```
select killedby.killerid as characterid, firstname, lastname, count(killedby.characterid) as killcount
    from character join killedby on (character.characterid = killedby.killerid)
    group by killedby.killerid, firstname, lastname
    order by killcount desc
```

it get the list with what i need and the character with the highest killcount on top, but i cannot figure out how to get at only this one row. we are not allowed to use the "limit" function.

i cannot just put a "max" around the count, as aggregate functions cannot be inside of each other, and i cant put the killcount in a where constraint, as it doesn't know what "killcount" is.

i tried putting the whole thing as a subquery in another query, but when i then select something like " max(killcount) as killcount, it outputs the same table as before.

i guess i just missed the obvious here? i'd be glad if someone could help me. please excuse any mistakes, i'm from germany :D

Answer (score 0):

> i cannot just put a "max" around the count, as aggregate functions cannot be inside of each other, and i cant put the killcount in a where constraint, as it doesn't know what "killcount" is.
>
> i tried putting the whole thing as a subquery in another query

That should have worked:

```
SELECT characterid, firstname, lastname, killcount
FROM (
  SELECT character.*, killcount, max(killcount) OVER () AS maxkillcount
  FROM character
  JOIN (
    SELECT killerid, count(characterid) as killcount
    FROM killedby
    GROUP BY killerid
  ) AS killing ON characterid = killerid
) AS _
WHERE killcount = maxkillcount;
```

Notice that unlike `LIMIT 1`, this might result in multiple rows if there are multiple characters that share the rank.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, i just get an error that says "aggregate functions not allowed in where clauses" (the last line)

Comment: Ah, it might need yet another subquery…

Comment: having count(killedby.characterid) >= ALL(select count(characterid) from killedby group by(killerid))     

seems to work.